# Datest, offsets and timezones in java

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm trying to understand the underlying mechanic of temporal utilities.

So, I made the next example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Instant.now().getEpochSecond());
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime());
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond());
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC));

        System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault().toString());
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
1460651620
1460651620182
1460651620
1460662420
Europe/Helsinki
```

My current systemDefault zoneId is Europe/Helsinki (+3 hours)
When we create `new Date()` it has the unix timestamp (UTC).

This is my base point to compare printed results.

**1.** In my third `System.out` I have the LocalDateTime with established timezone `systemDefault` but output is actually the same. I expected the bigger value (+3 hours).

**2.** In fourth output line I although have confusing result. I expected the same value with `new Date().getTime()`

Need some help to understand the output.

Answer (score 3):

Any method of type `getEpochSecond()` and `toEpochSecond()` give you the amount of seconds since the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, the time is running the same way whatever the timezone so the result is the same whatever the time zone chosen.

Assuming that you spent 10 minutes to write this question in your time zone, it will be the same 10 minutes in my time zone.

Answer (score 2):

> I have the LocalDateTime with established timezone systemDefault

No, you don't. You started with a `LocalDateTime`, but then you converted it into a `ZonedDateTime`. A `ZonedDateTime` is effectively a `LocalDateTime` with a `ZoneId` and an offset from UTC to handle ambiguity.

`LocalDateTime` doesn't have a `toEpochSecond()` method, because it doesn't represent a fixed point in time. It has `toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset)` because that "anchors" the local date/time to a fixed point in time by applying a UTC offset.

Compare that with `ZonedDateTime` which *does* have a parameterless `toEpochSecond()` method, because it represents a fixed point in time, with the additional context of a time zone. (You can either view a `ZonedDateTime` as an `Instant` with a `ZoneId`, or a `LocalDateTime` with a `ZoneId` and a `ZoneOffset`; they're equivalent, but personally I prefer the latter notion.)

Note that your code *could* give you a different result - if you were in a period where `LocalDateTime.now()` was ambiguous due to the clocks going back (typically at the end of daylight saving). In that case, `LocalDateTime.atZone` picks the earlier occurrence of that `LocalDateTime`, whereas in reality you *might* be experiencing the later occurrence. That's the difference between `LocalDateTime.now().atZone(zone)` and `ZonedDateTime.now(zone)` - the latter will always "know" the offset correctly.